# How to insert background color, font type and color, etc in embed code?

Tags: html, embed, webflow

I have the following checkout code to insert on a Webflow block. How can I set style, colors, fonts, etc of the displayed code?

```
<script src="https://cdn.chec.io/js/embed.js"></script>
<a href="https://checkout.chec.io/icqo4Y" data-chec-product-id="icqo4Y">Buy Now</a>
```

Sorry, I'm not a programmer or developer and can't find out any easy for me how to guide.

My goal is to have a button with following characteristics:

```
background color: #d36868
Font: Monserrat 20 px
Shape: Square
Text: Buy
```

Comment: Hi welcome to StackOverflow. I think you should have a look at https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_button.asp all the attributes you want to set are described there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like this?

```css
[data-chec-product-id] {
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: #d36868;
  font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
  font-weight: 100;
  font-size: 20px;
  text-decoration: none;
  border: 1px outset blue;
  height: 25px;
  width: 50px;
  text-align: center;
}

[data-chec-product-id]:hover {
  background-color: blue;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.chec.io/js/embed.js"></script>
<a href="https://checkout.chec.io/icqo4Y" data-chec-product-id="icqo4Y">Buy</a>
```

Comment: Thank you very much! Indeed that's what I was looking for!

Just one more thing, where shall I put the script, in which order? Because when i enter it in the html embed I don't get the right result. Thanks

Comment: I do know know what you mean. The script goes where you had it, the css goes in a style sheet and the link in the page in the body somewhere

Comment: Thanks again. It seems to be working now :) New to stackoverflow, I just marked your first answer as accepted.